# Error when I click view log button in task execution screen in Spring CLoud Dataflow Dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Good evening.

I have set up Spring Cloud Dataflow 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT to run spring batch's tasks in Openshift.
I registered an app, using a valid docker path, and created a task using this app.

When I execute the task from SCDF dashboard using an specific platform from the drop-down , the task gets properly executed on Openshift.
When I access the task execution screen, I click the button "View Logs", and I get the following error on screen:
"Log could not be retrieved.  Verify that deployments are still available."

In SCDF log file I get:
2020-09-15 14:12:16.546  WARN 7 --- [nio-9376-exec-1] .s.c.d.s.s.i.DefaultTaskExecutionService : Failed to retrieve the log, returning verification message.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Launcher found for the platform named 'default'.  Available platform names are [platform-test, platform-dev]
at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.findTaskLauncher(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:683)
at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.getLog(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:605)

I have seen that REST API endpoint(http://localhost:9393/tasks/logs/<external_exec_id>?platformName=platform-dev)  to get the log works properly,  but, from dashboard we are invoking http://localhost:9393/tasks/logs/<external_exec_id>, not including platformName.

should I configure anything, or add any attribute to the task execution to make this work, or is this a bug?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reporting. This is indeed a bug. Could you create an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues ?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/1553 thanks!